# How to run MATLAB in another computer from a MATLAB in one computer [Windows]

Tags: windows, matlab, ssh

I am running a MATLAB script from Windows machine-1 in which I invoke it to wake up another Windows machine-2. Now, I want to run a MATLAB script from cmd of Windows machine-2 and send a status if the task is done to machine-1.

A typical way to do is using remote desktop connection. However, I want to use MATLAB to run MATLAB script on another machine due to requirement of my project. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If running and utilizing the MATLAB processes on a separate machine is required, you can use the DCOM interface.

More information can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-application-as-a-dcom-server.html).

If you just have a command line interface, you can use this command to launch the script, gracefully handle errors from it and close the matlab interpreter after the script is finished:

```
C:\<a long path here>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, run('C:\<a long path here>\mfile.m'), catch, exit, end, exit"
```

Comment: This would require me to change settings in the other machine (machine-2). if that was my goal, I can do it manually instead.

Comment: I edited my answer for the case you have no access to those settings.

Comment: Let me rephrase it: I don't have access to the computer, let alone command line.

Comment: Are the computers on the same network? Do you have access to both  of the computers as Admin? basically you need to create an open channel communication between 2 standalone computers. There are various ways of doing this. Usually a ssh connection can do the trick. If the computers are not on the same network and behind a router/firewall you might have to set up a VPN.